# Get current category details the user is currently on in category.php

Tags: categories

I want to get the current category details that the user is on in category.php.

```
$category = get_the_category();
$slug  = $category[0]->slug; // Why is this an array ?
```

In most cases (where there are no sub-categories) it returns and array of single length.

But if there are sub-categories it (parent category and ) returns an array of 2 or more.

```
http://domain.com/category/cat-name/ -> get_the_category() returns an array of 2
http://domain.com/category/cat-name/sub-cat-name/ -> get_the_category() returns an array of 2
```

Comment: You seem to be getting categories. What is the question?

Comment: I want the current category the page is on at category.php. For categories that have sub-categories, I'm getting an array of categories - how can I make out which is the current category ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong function. Try:

```
$thiscat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
var_dump($thiscat);
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do with this information but you will get an object (stdClass) with ~15 items in it. You should be able to find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I've also got it from the following :

```
$cur_cat_id = get_cat_id(single_cat_title("",false));
$category = get_category($cur_cat_id);
```

But I guess s-ha-dum's solutions is better.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the following to retrieve the category ID of the current category archive:

`$cat_id = get_query_var('cat')`

to get the details, you can use:

`$cat = get_category( $cat_id )`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category